# MS Access - "phantom" process created by canceling report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have encountered a problem in Access 2010 for Windows:

1. Launch a report using doCmd.OpenReport
2. Set "Cancel = True" in an event associated with the report
3. Close Access
4. Access continues to run as a "phantom" process and must be killed in Task Manager.  Access cannot open another database until this process is killed.  The task initially shows some CPU utilization but quiets down to 0%.

I discovered this while using **doCmd.OpenReport** to launch a report. The report opens a form in the **Report_Open** event. The form prompts the user for report parameters and allows them to press "OK" to display the report or press "Cancel".  The **On Click** event for "Cancel" sets "Cancel = True".

It appears that **OpenReport()** is not responding gracefully to the cancel.  This seems like a frequently used technique so I hesitate to call it a bug and am wondering if I am doing something wrong.  Actually... the more I explain this, it does sound like a bug.  At this point, I am hoping somebody has a workaround or that I am missing something obvious.

This is just a simplified example I created to illustrate the problem:

**form**

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo errHandler

DoCmd.OpenReport "Test Report", acViewPreview, , , acDialog

Exit Sub

errHandler:
Select Case Err.Number
Case 2501   ' Cancelled by user, or by NoData event.
    MsgBox "Report cancelled, or no matching data.", vbInformation, "Information"
Case Else
    MsgBox "Error " & Err & ": " & Error$, vbInformation, "Form_Open()"
End Select
Resume Next

End Sub
```

**report**

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Have you tried the above code in a fresh database consisting only of a form and report? Have you compacted & repaired and decompiled recently?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.  I created a new DB on a different computer running Office 2010 and Win7 (vs Win8).  I copy and pasted the code I posted on this page.  Exact same problem.  MSACCESS.EXE remains running in Task Manager at 0% CPU utilization.  No other Access DB's can be opened until I kill the task.  I also verified that SP1 was installed on both computers.

Comment: I beg your pardon! I just realized that there was a further step to reproducing the error, and that is to close the database after running the code. Yes, I am getting this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the problem in this case is acDialog:

```
 DoCmd.OpenReport "Test Report", acViewPreview, , , acDialog
```

I think you will find:

```
 DoCmd.OpenReport "Test Report", acViewPreview
```

Works without problems.

Edit re Comment

You should not need to cancel the report. For the most part, it is better to avoid errors than to trap them, so check for data and get parameters before opening the form. Move the form from the report open event to step of its own and use DLookUp or a query to check for data before launching the form.

Comment: You are correct. Removing the acDialog parameter does avoid the problem in my example but I need the report to open as a dialog.  I tried allowing OpenReport() to default to acViewNormal and setting Modal and PopUp in the report's properties but the result was the same as using acDialog. Is there any reason I should not be using acDialog?  Is there an alternate method to allow the report to open as a dialog and still support Cancel?

Comment: Why not using on NoData properties of the report to allow the report to close itself properly ?

Comment: What about handling the "On No Data" event?  I believe it's accepted practice to set "Cancel = True" in that event to prevent an empty report from being displayed, correct?  I use it to display a msgbox indicating that there is not data to be displayed in the report.  This causes the exact same problem with OpenReport().

Comment: @iDevlop The problem is acDialog, it is not going to work with Cancel, AFAICT, hence my suggested workaround. Furthermore, you will still have the user cancel problem.

Comment: As an aside, I do not use the No Data event as a rule. It is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Thanks @Remou. Although I am not happy with what I have to do, based on the information you provided, you did discover what was causing the problem (cancel in report opened with OpenReport and acDialog).  It still boggles my mind that this doesn't work since I'm using techniques and code suggested frequently by Access developers and the MSDN Office Dev Center. I was hoping there was some manual garbage collection I could do to avoid this because it looks like this might be a problem with Access garbage collection.

Comment: Testing with the 2013 version, I find that the problem does not apply to that version.

Comment: Thanks again @Remou.  My brain didn't want to let go of what "should" have been correct, working code but I followed your recommendations and the problem is no longer occurring.  I now run the report parameters form up front, instead of from Report Open, and do a Dcount against the report's query before launching the report, instead of using On No Data.

Comment: I am afraid that opening a form in the report open event has never been a good idea, it is just an academic application. I am glad you got sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in a position to test this problem, so I'll just offer a generic solution: Remove the data/recordset/recordsource from the report definition.

You can apply the recordsource to the report after you have determined the parameters. If the report is canceled, it is canceled without ever having a data connection.